# how to run REXX file on mac?

Tags: macos, rexx

I am studying on how to use REXX programming language, but I face some difficulties while doing so. First of all, I am using macbook pro. Secondly, i have downloaded the interpreter from sourceforge and somehow i cant manage it to work, there's no dmg file that i could run. I would be glad if someone provided a solution.
I've tried to run rexx file via the terminal, but after that I get an error - access denied or command not found.

```
  P*******-MacBook-Pro:Desktop P******$ animal.rexx
  -bash: animal.rexx: command not found
```

Comment: In order to install the Regina Rexx interpreter you will need to use the tar command.  Documentation is available at a command prompt.  Open Terminal and type "man tar" without the quotes and hit return.

Comment: None of the available REXX distributions for UNIX/Linux and its brethren have a OS X-specific installation package. However, because OS X is essentially UNIX underneath the pretty GUI, all of them can be installed using the build-from-source path. As @cshneid implied above, you will have to use commands through Terminal. I recommend you Google to find the experiences of those who have already done this. Both REXX projects have active user communities; links can be found at the respective home pages, as well as via Google.

Answer (score 2):

Install the "Brew" package manager in your Mac — go to http://brew.sh/ and just follow the simple instructions there. Now you can type `brew install regina-rexx` to install Regina, and can run any ANSI REXX program using `regina program.rexx` on the command line.

To make REXX programs run as any program, you can add the line `#! /usr/local/bin/regina` (or wherever Regina has been installed, you may check this using `which regina`) as the first line in your program.

For ease of use in developing, use Sublime Text and its package manager to install the REXX syntax package.

Comment: ...or `#!/usr/bin/env regina`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration.  I was struggling to install oorexx on my Mac.

Download: http://www.oorexx.org/download.html

Read: http://rexxla.org/events/2007/presentations/renej2.pdf

I just recently got ooRexx installed on my Mac after going through the pdf mentioned above.  You really want to do the following specifically:

1. Run the .dmg installer on SourceForge link above.  This will place it in /usr/bin
2. Run the following script from pdf link above to create symbolics by using "**sudo /usr/bin/rexx**":

   ```
   "cd /opt/ooRexx/lib/ooRexx"
   "ls | rxqueue"
   do queued()
     parse pull line
     do i=1 to line~words()
       say "sudoln-s/opt/ooRexx/lib/ooRexx/"line~word(i)"/usr/lib/"line~word(i)
     end
   end
   "cd /opt/ooRexx/bin"
   "ls | rxqueue"
   do queued()
     parse pull line
     do i=1 to line~words()
       say "sudo ln -s /opt/ooRexx/bin/"line~word(i) "/usr/bin/"line~word(i)
     end
   end
   ```
3. Give permission to /opt/ and /opt/ooRexx

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /opt/ooRexx
   sudo chmod 755 /opt/ooRexx
   ```
4. Add to the **/System/Library/Automator/Run Shell Script.action/
   Contents/Resources/Shells.plist**

   ```
   <key>/usr/bin/rexx</key>
   <dict>
    <key>args</key>
    <array>
     <string>-e</string>
     <string>%</string>
     <string>--</string>
    </array>
   <key>script</key>
    <array>
     <string>do while lines()&#10;say linein()&#10;end</string>
     <string>parse arg arg1 arg2 arg3</string>
    </array>
   ```